# Database name in SQLLogin Dialog not getting updated in installshield basic MSI installer

Tags: installshield, basic-msi, installshield-2014

I am creating a basic MSI project. In the SQLLogin dialog, if I remove the database catalog name from the text box and then browse for an existing database, the value does not appear in the text box on clicking OK but if I click back and next then the value appears in the field (meaning it is getting updated but not showing I guess). It works fine otherwise if I do not update it after removing/editing the text box. Is this an open issue? Or am I missing some setting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a Basic MSI project, the internal Windows Installer user interface support will generally not refresh controls backed by a property until the dialog is closed and reopened. Edit controls will also not refresh if any value was entered by a user into the control. These are limitations of the MSI user interface functionality.